# Multilevel Use of jQuery .parent().eq(n) dosn't work

Tags: jquery

I read that .parent().parent(). ... sholud be replaced by .parent().eq(n) while n is the level.
Looking at demo, .parent().parent() is not equal to .parent().eq(1)

HTML

```
    <table id="Manager_tblPages" class="Manager_tblPages">
    <tbody>
         <tr class="Manager_trResultHeader">
            <td class="td1">
                <span class="Manager_cbxCheckAll">
                    <input id="cphBody_cphBody_Manager_cbxCheckAll" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphBody$cphBody$Manager_cbxCheckAll"></input>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$('.Manager_cbxCheckAll input').change(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().attr('class'));
    alert($(this).parent().eq(0).attr('class'));
    alert($(this).parent().parent().attr('class'));
    alert($(this).parent().eq(1).attr('class'));
});
```

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s2GX3/1/)

Any suggestion?

Comment: And now you can read that in most cases you should be using `closest()`, not `parents()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.parent()` returns the **single** element that contains the currently selected element so using `.eq()` makes no sense.

It's possible you want to use [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) as that returns **all** of the parent elements and `.eq()` should then work as expected.

[Updated Fiddle using parents()](http://jsfiddle.net/s2GX3/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) because [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) returns only one element.

```
$('.Manager_cbxCheckAll input').change(function () {
    console.log($(this).parents().attr('class'));
    console.log($(this).parents().eq(0).attr('class'));
    console.log($(this).parent().parent().attr('class'));
    console.log($(this).parents().eq(1).attr('class'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/43RF3/)

---

But it will be better to target those elements using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) like

```
$(this).closest('span').attr('class')
$(this).closest('td').attr('class')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/43RF3/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) instead of [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/).

From Docs:

```
The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a
single level up the DOM tree. Also, $( "html" ).parent() method returns a set containing 
document whereas $( "html" ).parents() returns an empty set.
```

Try this:

```
$('.Manager_cbxCheckAll input').change(function () {
        alert($(this).parent().attr('class'));
        alert($(this).parents().eq(0).attr('class'));
        alert($(this).parent().parent().attr('class'));
        alert($(this).parents().eq(1).attr('class'));
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s2GX3/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

use `.parents()` instead of `.parent()`:

```
 $('.Manager_cbxCheckAll input').change(function () {
   console.log($(this).parent().attr('class'));
   console.log($(this).parents().eq(0).attr('class'));
   console.log($(this).parent().parent().attr('class'));
   console.log($(this).parents().eq(1).attr('class'));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s2GX3/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.parents()` instead of `.parent()`:

```
console.log($(this).parents().eq(1).attr('class'));
```

However instead of multiple `.parent()` or `.parents()` and `.eq()`, you can use **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** instead:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$('.Manager_cbxCheckAll input').change(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().attr('class'));
    alert($(this).closest('span').attr('class'));
    alert($(this).parent().parent().attr('class'));
    alert($(this).closest('td').attr('class'));
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2GX3/5/)**